# Image submit raising ValidationError

Tags: python, html, django-models, django-forms

When i'm submitting a jpg image then it refreshes and shows 'This field required'validation error,so in views i tried to print(request.POST),it shows csrfmiddlewaretoken and pic in console but field validation is getting violated. Please correct me.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class picture(models.Model):
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='documents/')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import picture

class pictureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = picture
        fields = ['pic',]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import picture
from .forms import pictureForm
# Create your views here.
def pictureView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        form = pictureForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = pictureForm()
    return render(request,'home.html',{'form':form})
```

urls.py(APP level urls)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.pictureView, name = 'home')

]
```

urls.py(Directory level urls)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('post.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Media files

```
MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

template

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input value="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the doc: [uploaded-files-with-a-model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model)

you should initialize your form:

```
form = pictureForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

and in the template you need add [enctype="multipart/form-data"](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp)

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input value="submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Nope Sir, it didnt work.. still showing such validation error! while im uploading jpg file.

Comment: i extended the answer, now all sholud be fine.